# What is MSSQL driver equivalent for Sybase class com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

We have recently migrated from Sybase to Microsoft SQL Server, there's this method in the old code referencing Sybase driver

```
Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver");
```

I don't know for MSSQL what call should I call and update the above statement, can someone please help out?

Comment: Using `Class.forName` is - in a lot of situations - not necessary any more with JDBC 4 automatic driver loading. And where it is necessary (eg driver deployed in a WAR), you should be using a `DataSource` backed by a connection pool anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-2017) article says it is:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```